# Handle push notification when device is idle

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented Apple Push notification service. I have a requirement that I need to execute code in the device when a notification is received. When I followed the documentation, I found that there are two ways to do this

1. application:didReceiveRemoteNotification --> this is invoked if the app is running
2. application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions--> this is invoked if the app is brought to foreground because of the alert message view button.

But my requirement is different. I need to execute code when the app is in the background and also when the device is idle. Any thought how i can do it?

Thanks
-Srikanth

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with push notifications when the app is sleeping.

Comment: is there is any other way in which i can achieve this like using background tasks?